# Help identify this insect with a fan tail

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am trying to identify this creature... I took the shot in Medellín, Colombia. It is about 1cm in size.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is the [nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_(biology)) stage of a [**planthopper**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planthopper), an insect in a [suborder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auchenorrhyncha) of the [hemipterans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera).

The "fiber-optic-like" tail is actually made out of wax! From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planthopper#cite_note-ency-3)

> Nymphs of many [planthoppers] produce wax from special glands on the abdominal terga and other parts of the body. These are hydrophobic and help conceal the insects. Adult females of many families also produce wax which may be used to protect eggs.

The fact that there are about 12,5000 species of planthoppers and I am fully unfamiliar with the fauna of Colombia, I can only provide a quick image confirming that it is a planthopper. (Perhaps you have a field guide or key available to you to help ID to genus or species)

[image]

<sup>Credit: Malcolm Burrows, [source](https://www.washingtonpost.com/video/national/an-insect-jumps-using-gears/2013/09/12/2bb5d0dc-1bc1-11e3-82ef-a059e54c49d0_video.html)</sup>

You can find an aditional image of a species more similar to yours [here](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/multicolored-planthopper-nymph-with-fiberoptic-like-royalty-free-image/1169679644).

Comment: thanks so much! I was able to find this other video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPCRwuPpf9M