# Fairy little bug

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Can someone please enlighten me what kind of a creature is this sweet little friend? [image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include the size, approximate geographic location, and anything else you observed about this insect — e.g.s: behavior, what kind of plants are in the area. Where you saw this is essential to and the size may be very helpful for getting an accurate identification. You may also find it helpful to take the [tour] and then go through the [help] starting with [ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks.

Comment: related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/93176/16866

Answer (score 1):

This is a [planthopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planthopper) nymph. These are a quite diverse group of insects found worldwide. Which one you have is open to further answers, and will be based on your locality and the species of plants and insects in that location.

The furry "tail" and the fish-like mouth-parts/head give it away.